# Django: retrieve all galleries containing one public photo at least

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, count

excuse me for my ugly english) !

Imagine these very simple models :

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    is_public = models.BooleanField('Public', default=False)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photos', related_name='galleries', null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to select all `Gallery` instances which contain *at least* one public photo (and if possible adding a `photos__count` attribute which contains the number of public photos).

I tried this query :

```
Gallery.objects.all()\
    .annotate(Count('photos'))\
    .filter(photos__is_public=True)
```

It seems to be okay, but :
- the query is strange
- the added attribute `photos__count` on each gallery will contain the total number of photos on this gallery, instead of the number of public photos in this gallery.

I thin that the hard-coded sql query I need is that :

```
SELECT `gallery`.* , COUNT(`gallery_photos`.`photo_id`) 
FROM `gallery` 
    INNER JOIN `gallery_photos` ON (`gallery`.`id` = `gallery_photos`.`gallery_id`) 
    INNER JOIN `photo` ON (`gallery_photos`.`photo_id` = `photo`.`id`) 
WHERE `photo`.`is_public` = True 
GROUP BY gallery.id ;
```

Any idea to fix it ?

Thank you ! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The django documentation is at

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses

and my experience says that the following query:

```
Gallery.objects.filter(photos__is_public=True).annotate(Count('photos'))
```

would give you galleries with at least one photo that is public and a count of only photos that are public. The only thing is that it will exclude galleries with zero public photos but it sounds like you don't care about that. Have you tested the above query?

If it still doesn't return the right data then annotate is probably changing the returned data by causing it to return only galleries where all are public. In that case you could use the "extra" method to get the count you want.

```
Gallery.objects.filter(photos__is_public=True).extra(select={
  "photo_count": """
  SELECT COUNT(`gallery_photos.id`)
      FROM `gallery_photos`
  WHERE `gallery_photos.gallery_id` `gallery.id AND
        `gallery_photos.is_public = True
  """})
```

Jason Christa's exclude method may also work.

Comment: This works : ``Gallery.objects.filter(photos__is_public=True).annotate(Count('photos'))``

Thank you very much (and Jason too, your query works ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

**Edit, updated to add count:**

```
SELECT `gallery`.*, 'a'.'count' 
FROM `gallery` 
inner join (
    select `gallery`.`id`, count(*) as count
    from `gallery_photos` 
    INNER JOIN `photo` ON (`gallery_photos`.`photo_id` = `photo`.`id`) 
    where `photo`.`is_public` = True
    group by `gallery`.`id`
) a on `gallery`.`id` = 'a'.'id'
WHERE `photo`.`is_public` = True
```

Comment: It seems that your query make two SELECT, and mine one. So I think that my query os more optimized. :p

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
Gallery.objects.filter(photos__is_public=True).annotate(Count('photos'))
```

I believe you just got your filter ordering wrong but I have not set up your models to test that assumption.

Try number two:

```
Gallery.objects.exclude(photos__is_public=False).annotate(Count('photos'))
```

That should be exclude all galleries where none of the photos are public and return a count of what is and isn't public.

Comment: Hi,

This doesn't work because it selects galleries where *ALL* photos are public. But I need to selects galleries where *at least one* photo is public. Moreover your ``phots__count`` attribute will contain the number of all photos (public AND not public).

Thank you for helping me all the same ;-) !

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
Gallery.objects.filter(photos__is_public=True)\
               .annotate(Count('photos__is_public'))
```

Comment: Ha, Jason's queryset is right and shorter, IMO. What a shame I typed even more keys here =], need to sleep now... The filter is applied to rows of the joined inner table, only row w/ is_public=Ture will be left and counted.